# Entity custom displays

Tags: 7, entities

Is there a way to create multiple displays for an existing entity?

The node has already Full content, Teaser, RSS, Search index, Search result display types. I was wondering if I can add more to these or to any other entity.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [display suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds). this is your answer

Comment: I think `hook_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info)` is what I was looking for. I just need it so I can invoke it from code later on.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the answer I was looking for:

```
function hook_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['entity_type']['view modes']['custom mode'] = array(
    'label' => t('Custom view mode'),
    'custom settings' => FALSE
  );
}
```